# Always get this error when I use upload images - Using Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework

```
Warning: include_once(Zend/Http/Client.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/hotbuzz/public_html/include/Zend/Loader.php on line 83

Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening 'Zend/Http/Client.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/hotbuzz/public_html/include;.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/hotbuzz/public_html/include/Zend/Loader.php on line 83

    Warning: require_once(Zend/Exception.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/hotbuzz/public_html/include/Zend/Loader.php on line 87

    Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'Zend/Exception.php' (include_path='/home/hotbuzz/public_html/include;.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/hotbuzz/public_html/include/Zend/Loader.php on line 87
```

Always get this error when i use image upload in the script .. I m using Zend Framework .. I i dont know what to do ?

My Zend path : public_html/include/zend
phpinfo : hotbuzz.in/phpinfo.php

I have not configured path to Zend in .htaccess

?

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
set_include_path(dirname(realpath(__FILE__)).PATH_SEPARATOR.get_include_path());
```

Answer (score 1):

Does your include path point to the library files or just the root of the Zend project. The include path needs to point to the directory that contains the directory structure

- Zend

  - Acl
  - Auth
  - etc...

which maybe the library directory of the files you downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

There is something weird in your include path ;.:

I think you probably have use the syntax of windows in a linux server.

You should use PATH_SEPARATOR the be sure that you will have the right one on every server.